# Trim the repeated value in URL

Tags: login, urls

```
http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fsarkari%2F&_wpnonce=b5e3b954df&redirect_to=http://localhost/sarkari/2017/06/01/new-sample-post/
```

i want to get only this url part http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fsarkari%2F&_wpnonce=b5e3b954df
how to trim rest of part in php

Comment: How is this link being generated in the first place? Please [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/268902/edit) your question and provide the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Parse Url, check params, and build it again:

```
$url = "http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fsarkari%2F&_wpnonce=b5e3b954df&redirect_to=http://localhost/sarkari/2017/06/01/new-sample-post/";

function trimUrlParams($url, array $params) 
{
 $parts = parse_url($url);
 parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
 $newQuery = array();

 if (is_array($query) && sizeof($query) > 0 ) {
  foreach ($query as $variable=>$value) {
   if (in_array($variable, $params)) {
    $newQuery[$variable] = $value;
   }
  }
 }

 return $parts['scheme']."://".$parts['host'].$parts['path']."?". http_build_query($newQuery);
}


$newUrl = trimUrlParams($url, array('action', 'redirect_to', '_wpnonce'));
```

Comment: got this errorFatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function http_build_url()

Comment: @JayKapoor I changed `http_build_url` to `http_build_query`. It should work now.

Comment: again got this Warning: http_build_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Comment: i pass this URL $uri= $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      
     $url= wp_logout_url($uri);

Comment: i got this URL back  
http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout

Comment: but i want this 
http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fsarkari%2F&_wpnonce=b5e3b954df

Comment: just tested in phpfiddle, it works fine -- http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wdid-23by

Comment: copy and past the code again, usage of `http_build_url` to `http_build_query` is different.

Comment: oh u didnt get my question,

Comment: as  i told i only want the first redirect value not another like this
http://localhost/sarkari/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=%2Fsarkari%2F&_wpnonce=b5e3b954df

Comment: just i want to trim or remove the repeated reditect_to value after the first reditect_to value